# Java Executable Application

Tags: java, jar, applet, executable, double-click

I am an amateur Java programmer, and I have just started learning how Java applets work. However, I wanted to make an applet for my Chrome browser, but it no longer works because Chrome doesn't support NPAPI plugins (like Java and Unity 3D). I want to make a standalone Java executable similar to Minecraft. The idea is that once I double-click on the `.jar` file, it opens the application and runs the program.

The program displays text and images based on input from a text box.

How do I make the `.jar` automatically open on a double click?

Comment: Check the following link [Applet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17013405/are-applets-now-deprecated)

Comment: Why invest effort into a dead technology?

Comment: @KlasLindbäck See the last line I edited my question.

Comment: Forget about applets. They were cool in 1997, when Java was new. Applets are going away, and will be deprecated in Java 9.

Answer (score 2):

To make a JAR which can be launched by double clicking, you have to make it an executable JAR. There must be a file `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` inside the JAR with key-value pairs that point to the main class (the class with the `main` method) to run.

See [Lesson: Packaging Programs in JAR Files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/) in Oracle's Java Tutorials to learn exactly how to create an executable JAR.

Answer (score 0):

No.
After the release of Chrome version 45, you’ll need to use an alternate web browser to load content that requires a NPAPI plugin.

But you can create application using Java Network Programming will help to create the application.