# Java applet in JDK1.9

Tags: java, applet, deprecation-warning

I want to know how to fix the warning which I get whenever I run applet code. Currently I m using jdk 1.9 version.

The warning which I get on running applet code is:

```
Warning: Applet API and AppletViewer are deprecated.
```

Comment: The solution is to stop using applets. They're dead and all time spent upon them is a waste.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45535112/why-applets-in-jdk-9-are-deprecated, and http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/289 and https://www.java.com/en/download/faq/jdk9_plugin.xml.  And if you are one such vendor (see last link) ... make those plans now, 'cos applets won't be un-deprecated!

Comment: And if you want to know what is the meaning of that warning then `Deprecated means be usable but regarded as obsolete and best avoided, typically because it has been superseded.` From wikipedia

Comment: But in the case of applets, I would not be surprised if deprecation is flagging that support will dropped entirely pretty soon.  See the explanations in the links and read between the lines.

Comment: @StephenC *"support will dropped entirely pretty soon"* It's really a moot point how Oracle describes the deprecation or phasing out of applets, given most browsers have already completely dropped support for them. Applets. Are. **Dead.**