# What happen to my keyListener?

Tags: java

In the code below, I am trying to create a frogger game with a "white dot" representing the frog. However, everything went well until I add keyListener, which I just learnt from watching severl youtube video. The problem is that the "FINAL" in the public class is red-underlined. I did everything as the video I watched; I have "keyPress"... I do believe there's something wrong with using "this" in the public void init. Someone please help.

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

public class FINAL extends Applet implements Runnable,KeyListener{
Thread t;
Image BGImage;
Image i;
Graphics DG;
int x =0;
int y = 100;
int a;
int b;
int c;
int d;
int e;
int f;

int h = 20;
int j = 480;

public void init()
{
    this.addKeyListener(this);  
    setSize(500,500);
  BGImage = getImage(getCodeBase(),"frogger_background.jpg");

}

    public void start()
     {
        if(t==null)
        {
         t=new Thread(this,"New Thread");
         t.start();
        }
     }

    public void stop()
    {
        if(t!=null)
        {
         t=null;
        }
    }

    public void run()
    {
        Thread t1=Thread.currentThread();
        while(t==t1)  
        { 
         repaint();
         try
         {  
          Thread.sleep(100); //slepp 100 ms
         }
         catch(Exception e)
         {   }
        }
    }

    @Override
 public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
     //int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
     switch (e.getKeyCode()) {
        case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN: 
            j = j + 1;
            break;

        case KeyEvent.VK_UP: 
            j = j - 1;
            break;

        case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT: 
            h = h - 1;
            break;

        case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
            h = h + 1;
            break;
    }
 }

@Override
 public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){

 }

 @Override
public void update(Graphics g){
        i = createImage(this.getSize().width,this.getSize().height);
        DG = i.getGraphics();
    paint(DG);
        g.drawImage(i,0,0,500,500,this);
}



@Override
 public void paint(Graphics g){
     //Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
     x = x+1;
     a = x%500+30;
     b = 5*(x%500);
     c = 3*(x%500);
     d = 4*(x%500)+50;
     e = 6*(x%500)+10;
     f = 7*(x%500)+20;
     g.drawImage(BGImage, 0, 0, this);

     g.setColor(new Color(160,82,45));
     g.fillRoundRect(a, y, 120, 35, 5, 5);

          g.setColor(new Color(160,82,45)); //Wood#2
     g.fillRoundRect(b, y+50, 120, 35, 5, 5);


          g.setColor(new Color(160,82,45)); //Wood#3
     g.fillRoundRect(c, y+100, 120, 35, 5, 5);


          g.setColor(Color.RED);
     g.fillRoundRect(d, 300, 60, 25, 5, 5);


          g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
     g.fillRoundRect(e, 350, 60, 25, 5, 5);


          g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
     g.fillRoundRect(f, 400, 60, 25, 5, 5);

          g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
     g.fillOval(j,h,20,20);
     if (j<0){

     }
     System.out.println("j =" + j);
     System.out.println("h =" + h);

}

}
```

Comment: what is the error ?red underline mean there is a error

Comment: you have to implement all abstract methods not one or two.so where did you implement `public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)` ?

Comment: Don't call your class `FINAL` . The word `final` is a Java keyword.  Even though `FINAL` doesn't conflict with it you should avoid using it because it is confusing.

Comment: Applets are dead - you should move on to technologies people still use

Comment: @Fast Snail, the underline says "FINAL is not abstract and does not override abstract method keyType(KeyEvent) in KeyListener.

Comment: @Fast Snail where should I put the keyType tho? Should I put it with a "@Override"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FINAL` does not fulfil the contractual requirements of the `KeyListener` `interface`, specifically `keyTyped`.

You need to add...

```
@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
}
```

to your class

`Applet` is also deprecated and you should avoid using it.

- [Oracle reveals Java Applet API deprecation plan](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2016/08/24/oracle_reveals_java_applet_api_deprecation_plan/)
- [Why applets in JDK 9 are deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45535112/why-applets-in-jdk-9-are-deprecated)
- [The clock is ticking: The Java browser plugin will be deprecated soon](https://jaxenter.com/clock-ticking-java-browser-plugin-will-deprecated-soon-131546.html)
- [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/moving-to-a-plugin-free-web)
- [Oracle's finally killing its terrible Java browser plugin](https://www.theverge.com/2016/1/28/10858250/oracle-java-plugin-deprecation-jdk-9)

I would recommend investing time in either [Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html) or [JavaFX](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/overview/jfxpub-overview.htm) instead

Comment: thank you so much, and @Fast Snail. One more thing tho. Even the code runs fine, the "white dot" (j,h,20,20) is not moving :(. When I press arrow keys, nothing happen.

Comment: So, KeyListener is picky, adding in an applet and you have double the trouble. The key issue is KeyListener requires the component to be focusable and have key focus. You could try calling requestFocusInWindow