# JApplet via Java Web Start 9 and 10 seems to take width as height setting

Tags: java, applet, java-web-start, java-9, java-10

I am porting a Java Web Start application, which worked fine under Oracle JDK Java 7 and 8, to Java 9 and 10. What remains to be solved is a layout bug:

The application is a former Java applet which is running as `JApplet`,
using the `<applet-desc>` element with `width=1000`, `height=650`.

However under Java 9 and 10 it renders the window with `width=1000`, `height=1000`, providing an unwanted lower display area.

I tried to resize the window, but without success. The dimension values of the targeted container get updated, but the rendered window will not change its size.

Can anyone confirm this behaviour?

I would prefer a simple fix rather than porting the applet into a regular Swing application.

Update: I confirmed the same behaviour in a JWS JApplet application from another party.

Comment: Have they not [deprecated applet](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/289)? Also => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45535112/why-applets-in-jdk-9-are-deprecated

Comment: It is deprecated, but as long as it is included in a Java release, it should work. (Though this bug and the difficulties with the deprecated JAXB makes one wonder, if there is some nudging at work)