# How to fix "Command 'appletviewer' not found" in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, applet

When I am trying to run an applet using appletviewer from ubuntu terminal it says

Command 'appletviewer' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install openjdk-11-jdk
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk

I have tried to install openjdk-11-jdk using 'sudo apt install openjdk-11-jdk'
it installed perfectly. writing java -version in terminal shows

openjdk version "11.0.2" 2019-01-15
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.2+9-Ubuntu-3ubuntu118.04.3)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.2+9-Ubuntu-3ubuntu118.04.3, mixed mode, sharing)

writing 'which java' shows
/usr/bin/java

but writing 'which appletviewer' shows nothing.

Please help me, I am new to Linux and java.

Comment: Applets are **dead**. Do not learn applets.

Comment: It was [removed](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/11-relnote-issues-5012449.html#JDK-8200146).  Applets have been deprecated since Java 9.

Answer (score 0):

`appletviewer` was [removed in JDK 11](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/11-relnote-issues-5012449.html#JDK-8200146), having been [deprecated in JDK 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45535112/why-were-applets-deprecated-in-jdk-9).

Applets are [no longer supported](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/applet/Applet.html):

> **Deprecated.**
>
> *The Applet API is deprecated, no replacement.*

You'll need to install an older JDK, or modify your software.