# What happens in this code snippet with the Applet class?

Tags: java, oop, applet

Can someone help me understand what is happening in this code?

```
public class aClass extends Applet{
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        g.drawRect(0, 0, 400, 200);
    }
}
```

My understanding is this, I create a *class* of name ***aClass*** that *inherit*(because it becomes a *daughter*) *methods* and *attributes* of the ***Applet*** *class*; then *overwrites* the ***paint*** *method*(which had been inherited from Applet), and this *method* expects an *object* as a *parameter* (which we put name ***g***) created from the *class* ***Graphics***, and then we call the ***drawRect*** *method* that is proper to the ***g*** *object* (which was created from the ***Graphics*** *class*); so that when the ***aClase*** *class* is executed, a *rectangle is drawn*, ***is it like that?***

Comment: *"is it like that?"* more or less. Painting's bit of a black box/magic.  You can have a look at [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) if you're interested in know "how" it works. Applet's are dead - [Why were applets deprecated in JDK 9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45535112/why-were-applets-deprecated-in-jdk-9) best not to waste your time

Comment: Thanks, I understand, but it was only to understand better how some things work in object-oriented programming, and I wanted to understand this example,  because I found it curious, especially about ***(Graphics g)***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Applets are an old, deprecated technology and you should consider newer technologies such as [Java Web Start](https://java.com/en/download/faq/java_webstart.xml). That said, your understanding is mostly correct apart from some of the terminology.

> I create a class of name aClass that inherit(because it becomes a daughter) methods and attributes of the Applet class;

Extending a class means that you create a new sub-class (in this case `aClass`) which is based off of the public contract and private implementation of the super class (`Applet`). The way that `aClass` behaves should respect the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) at a high level meaning that anywhere you can use an `Applet`, you should be able to use an `aClass` too. This means respecting the public contract of `Applet` in `aClass`.

> Applet class; then overwrites the paint method(which had been inherited from Applet),

Partially correct. `aClass` will **override** `paint` meaning that it will called when invoking `paint` on an instance of `aClass` rather than the default definition in `Applet`. It does not *overwrite*, as it is still possible to call the `super` implementation of this method. You should also annotate overriden method with the `@Override` annotation

```
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g){
    // calls paint from higher up the inheritance tree
    super.paint(g); 
    g.drawRect(0, 0, 400, 200);
}
```

> this method expects an object as a parameter (which we put name g) created from the class Graphics,

Yes, or just like `aClass` extends `Applet`, this could be some class that also extends `Graphics`.

e.g. `class FooGraphics extends Graphics { ... }`

> and then we call the drawRect method that is proper to the g object (which was created from the Graphics class);

Yup. Part of the public contract to the `Graphics` class.

> so that when the aClase class is executed, a rectangle is drawn, is it like that?

Whenever the `Applet` framework decides to update the view it will call this method which has the effect of drawing a rectangle.