# How can i work with an Java appletviewer with IntelliJ?

Tags: java, applet

i'm trying to work with an applet to draw thing with java.
I'm trying to work with an Java applet and not a main, how can i make it work with IntelliJ ?
Thanks

Comment: [Applets are deprecated as of JDK 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45535112/why-were-applets-deprecated-in-jdk-9). Is there a particular reason that you need to be using them?

Comment: Hello, there is none, just my teacher forcing us to try it, but it looks useless

Comment: "just my teacher forcing us to try it" Please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). Note: I wrote that more than a year or so before applets were deprecated. There is no longer any excuse for teachers not to update their courses.

Comment: *"to draw thing"* Extend a `JPanel`. Show it in a `JFrame`. If the teacher complains that it's not an applet, ask them to ***show*** you how to do that.

Comment: Hello , thanks for your answer, that's what i'll do, he told me to install a very old version of java to teach me applets. I read your post about how swing looks better nowadays. Have a good day