# How to run applet in jdk-14 and Chrome?

Tags: java, html, applet

I'm writing an simple applet using JDK-14 in `MyApp.java`:

```
public class MyApp extends Applet {
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawString("My App", 20, 20);
    }
}
```

Then I created `index.html` and add the following line to `<head>` tag:

`<applet code="MyApp.class" width=200 height=600></applet>`

When I saved and reload my web page in `Chrome`, nothing displayed.

Then, I tried to execute the `MyApp.java` run it in `Terminal`, the following error occured:

```
Note: MyApp.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Error: Main method not found in class MyApp, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)
or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application
```

I read that the `applet` doesn't require `public static void main(String[] args)`.

Is there any problem with Chrome or I didn't import something ?

Comment: [Applets are deprecated.](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.desktop/java/applet/package-summary.html)  You will need to use an older browser, and I suspect an older version of Java which supports the browser plug-in, in order to work with applets.  You would be better off following tutorials which don’t ask you to work with applets at all.

Comment: In addition to what VGR said, back before applets were deprecated, you didn't test them by running them but rather by viewing them with [appletviewer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/tools/appletviewer.htm) which was deprected in JDK 9 and removed in JDK 11.

Comment: Besides the points well covered by @VGR & David Conrad, note that the HTML is invalid. An applet element should ***not*** (even when browsers **did** support the applet plug-in) be put in the `head` of the document. 
Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). (Note: that document was written long *before* applets were deprecated.)

Answer (score 0):

Applet is `deprecated` since Java 9 [check here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45535138/8749662)

If still you want to use applet then you must go through java 8 and use browsers with older version which supports Applet (not recommended).