# IsEnabled not working when a function is triggered in Java applet

Tags: java, applet, awt

I want a button ("closeButton") to grey out when the function "openExplanations" run. But it is not working.

Gives error
Cannot invoke "javax.swing.JButton.setEnabled(boolean)" because "this.closeButton" is null

```
//the UI
private void initUI() {

hintArea = new JDialog(this);

buttonsPanel = new JPanel();
buttonsPanel.setAlignmentX(0.0f);

JButton closeButton = new JButton(" Close Hint ");
        closeButton.setActionCommand("closeHint");
        closeButton.setVisible(true);
        closeButton.addActionListener(this);
        closeButton.setFocusable(false);
        closeButton.setIcon(createImageIcon("images/constraint/close.gif"));
        buttonsPanel.add(closeButton, BorderLayout.WEST);

hintArea.add(buttonsPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}


private void openExplanation(){
        closeButton.setEnabled(false);
    }
```

Comment: And you are using (or learning) applets because .... ?  Applets were deprecated a long time ago.  Web browsers no longer support them.  Java (9 onwards) is progressively removing support.  Writing new applet code (or learning how to do it) is nugatory.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45535112

Comment: Coz I'm working on a legacy code originally written in 2002. It's research work, so got to stick to the interface. @StephenC

Comment: @StephenC [Everything old is new again!](https://www.webswing.org/docs/23.1/configure/applet.html)

Answer (score 0):

This

```
JButton closeButton = new JButton(" Close Hint ");
```

creates a [*variable shadow*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing). Remove the type declaration. And use `this`.

```
this.closeButton = new JButton(" Close Hint ");
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. 
I also want to do this for another button. I tried implementing the same thing but that didn't work. 
This is the code for the other button:
openExplanationPanel = new JPanel();
        openExplanationPanel.setAlignmentX(0.0f);
        JButton openExplanationButton = new JButton(
                isLevel1HintExplanation ? Content.getLevel1Question() : Content.getLevel1QuestionAgain());

Comment: Why are you creating another panel? `buttonsPanel.add(openExplanationButton, BorderLayout.EAST);` should do it. Maybe.

Comment: Cool. It could make it work. Thanks a lot!